# AccessoryView on TextView without Keyboard?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitextview, uikeyboard, accessoryview

I'm learning about AccessoryViews and testing the Apple example: [KeyBoardAccessory](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Listings/Classes_ViewController_m.html)

I'm trying to show the accessory view avoiding the Keyboard to show, but I can't do it :-(

I'm returning NO in textViewShouldBeginEditing to avoid keyboard and animating the resize of the TextView before return, but nothing happens.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    // Make the keyboard appear when the application launches.
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [textView becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)aTextView {
    NSLog(@"textViewShouldBeginEditing");
    /*
     You can create the accessory view programmatically (in code), in the same nib file as the view controller's main view, or from a separate nib file. This example illustrates the latter; it means the accessory view is loaded lazily -- only if it is required.
     */

    if (textView.inputAccessoryView == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AccessoryView" owner:self options:nil];
        // Loading the AccessoryView nib file sets the accessoryView outlet.
        textView.inputAccessoryView = accessoryView;    
        // After setting the accessory view for the text view, we no longer need a reference to the accessory view.
        self.accessoryView = nil;
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    textView.frame = CGRectMake(textView.frame.origin.x, textView.frame.origin.y, textView.frame.size.width, textView.frame.size.height - 100);

    [UIView commitAnimations];    

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: could you explain the outcome you are trying to get in more depth? You want only the accessory view that is associated with the keyboard to come up when you click a text view instead of keyboard and accessory view?

Comment: yes, i want to show only accessory, however i was wrong about the property to use, i need an inputView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inputAccessoryView is for a view to come up above the standard apple virtual keyboard. If you don't allow the on-screen keyboard to appear, then the inputAccessoryView will not appear either.

If you ONLY want a custom keyboard to show, and NOT the standard on-screen keyboard, you should use inputView instead of inputAccessoryView. See the difference between inputView and inputAccessoryView here:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html

Answer (score 1):

If you really want an accessoryview only, you have to set the inputview to a view with no height.

Answer (score 0):

On Xcode 6, the ios 8.1 Simulator show the keyboard hidden by default. (I have to select "Toggle software keyboard" to have it appear.)

I love this, because only my accessoryview appear.

I there a way to reproduce this programmatically(toggle keyboard on and off, no dismiss)

Thanks!